# Flutter form with attachment (file upload)

Tags: flutter, multipartform-data, attachment, filepicker

I am trying to build a Flutter form with 2 text fields and 1 field for an attachment:

```
Text Field 1
Text Field 2
Attachment
Send Data Button
```

This is to make a POST request and send these 3 values to my server, store the file locally and get the name of the file in the database. This backend logic is already covered.

I was trying to use a MultiPart request as follows:

```
Future makePostRequest(
  String title, int subjectid, int teacherid, String limitDate) async {
var url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/newHomework');
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
var headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'};
print(this.file);
Uint8List data = await file.readAsBytes();
List<int> list = data.cast();
request.files
    .add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('text', list, filename: 'tarea1'));
request.headers.addAll(headers);
request.fields['title'] = title;
request.fields['limitDate'] = limitDate;
request.fields['subjectid'] = subjectid.toString();
request.fields['teacherid'] = teacherid.toString();
request.fields['ext'] = '.txt';

var res = await request.send();
return res.stream.bytesToString().asStream().listen((event) {
  var parsedJson = json.decode(event);
  print(parsedJson);
});
```

}

But I do not know how to do this:

Include a button in the form to add the attachment (will only be text files, and only 1 file always) and then send all of this information with the `Send Data Button`.

Maybe I am approaching this from an incorrect perspective... Any ideas on how to do this?

Update makePostRequest method, now getting error: `Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'readAsBytes'`

Comment: What error was raised?

Comment: I have updated the makePostRequest method, getting error: `Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'readAsBytes'`. Also updated the method in the original question.

Comment: what is the type of File?
Look, you have to specify your content type when reading the file, and also in  MultipartRequest you have to pass file extension using .fields['ext'], it should be mimetype (in your case (a text file)) should be text/plain, refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types.

Comment: I updated the method adding headers (that were not there) and the extension with `request.fields['ext'] = '.txt';`. How can I specify the content type when reading the file? Maybe thats what I am missing here... still getting: `Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'readAsBytes'`.